# Image Buttons onchange when clicked in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, sapui5

How can I change the image button when clicked? It should change to other image button.

```
var offButton =  new sap.ui.commons.Button({
        id : "offIcon",
        icon : "img/off.png" ,
        press :function(e) {
            alert("clicked");
          var noButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
            id:"noIcon",
            icon : "img/no.png" ,
            });
    noImage.addStyleClass("noButtonImage");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining two buttons, this might not work, check this:

```
var offButton =  new sap.ui.commons.Button({
        id : "offIcon",
        icon : "img/off.png" ,
        press :function(e) { 
                var myBtn = sap.ui.getCore().byId("offIcon");
                myBtn.setIcon(''); // this removes the icon
               }
        });
```

On Off Example:

```
var offButton =  new sap.ui.commons.Button({
        id : "offIcon",
        icon : "img/off.png" ,
        press :function(e) { 
                var myBtn = sap.ui.getCore().byId("offIcon");
                if (myBtn.getIcon() == '' || myBtn.getIcon == 'null') {
                  myBtn.setIcon('img/off.png');
                } else {
                myBtn.setIcon(''); // this removes the icon
                }
               }
        });
```

Comment: I tried your code Zyrex, when I clicked on off button image,firstly Iam getting empty button ,when clicked it then the Nobutton Image is apperaring..vice versa .Any idea what might may be the reason????

Comment: thats what it should do right? Otherwise I dont get your point you are trying to achieve...

Comment: My requirement is to show,whenever i clicked on button Image it should directly show other button Image ,not the empty button viceversa

Comment: Hey Zyrex, I am able to resolve the empty button issue ,but let me know how to get back the button Image when clicked again.

Comment: you need to do it vice versa, like in my code, you check if there is already an icon in use, if not set the icon, if there is already one icon in use remove it

Comment: Thanks Zyrex ,it helped me out.